# Call runonuithread from asynchTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-relativelayout

I am a bit stumped on a problem and forgive me as I am very new to android development.  I did some searching and found quite a few differing opinions.  I have an AsynchTask that calls a webservice and returns a bunch of json results.  I have to (& want to) run my webservice asynchronously.  the result set will need to be rendered inline within a RelativeLayout.  I attempted to do this in my asynchronous thread but Android doesn't allow updating the UI from anything that isn't the main thread.

I see the Runonuithread but I can't call my asynchtask from my ui thread.

What is the best way to call my webservice asynchronously, get the results, and then update the mainUI on the original thread.  Is there a best practices from an architecture perspective.

Comment: onPostExecute() is run on the ui thread, otherwise you will need to use a Handler.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you very much!!!  I want to mark it as answered, I am ASSuming that the way to do that is by the "star" on the left?

Comment: Here I will post an answer, and then you can select it.

Comment: How about on progressUpdate? I think that's run on the UI as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onPostExecute() is run on the ui thread, so try using that method to do your work.  Otherwise, you can use the Handler class to communicate between threads.