# AsyncTask not updating the TextView inside First fragment in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I've started programming for Android (from iOS), and I working with the boiler plate code that ADT generates for me when I choose Activity+Scrollable tabs option in the new Project wizard. In the code below I've marked the same in comments.

The scenario is I enter text in an editText, press the button and fetch some data from a webservice. I wish to put this data in the appropriate fragment (there are 3 fragments) inside a view pager. I am getting the data and I am able to set it on Fragment 2 and Fragment 3 when I swipe, but the data that is relevant to Fragment 1 is not getting set once the AsycTask is complete. However, after swiping to fragment 3, when I come back to fragment 1, the data is there.

Here is my code:

## Activity

```
public class XXXX extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

//My additions to the boiler plate source generated by ADT
public ArrayList<String> p1T,p2T,p3T,p4T;
private EditText editText;
private Button button;
private boolean flag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.konjugation);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //My additions to the boiler plate source below
    flag=false;
    p1T = new ArrayList<String>(6); 
    p2T = new ArrayList<String>(6); 
    p3T = new ArrayList<String>(6); 
    p4T = new ArrayList<String>(6); 

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = editText.getText().toString();
            if(!url.isEmpty()) {
                url="http://.../?q="+editText.getText().toString();
                PAsyncTask task = new PAsyncTask();
                task.execute(url);
            }

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
            if(flag==true) {
                if(pos==0) DummySectionFragment.setText(p4T,p1T);
                if(pos==1) DummySectionFragment.setText(p4T,p2T);
                if(pos==2) DummySectionFragment.setText(p4T,p3T);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("ts","data not arrived");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.konjugation, menu);
    return true;
}
```

## PagerAdapter

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        int pos = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if(pos==0) DummySectionFragment.setText(p4T,p1T);
        else if(pos==1) DummySectionFragment.setText(p4T,p2T);
        else if(pos==2) DummySectionFragment.setText(p4T,p3T);
    }

}
```

## AsyncTask

```
private class PAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : params) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        try {
            p1T.clear();
            p2T.clear();
            p3T.clear();

            //do something very important with the result here

             flag=true;
            //hoping that somehow the viewpager adapter will refresh the view
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Viewpager's fragment

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    private static TextView dummyTextView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_konjugation_dummy, container, false);
        dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        return rootView;
    }

    public static void setText(ArrayList<String> s, ArrayList<String> t) {
        try {
            DummySectionFragment.dummyTextView.setText("");
            for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
                DummySectionFragment.dummyTextView.append(s.get(i)+" "+t.get(i)+"\n\n");
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I feel kinda lost, after reading some threads here. Please help :-(

Answer (score 0):

you should update it inside of runOnUiThread() method, which takes a runnable object as argument, so you can pass your implementation in it.

Comment: @blackbelt Yes, that was the question I was about to ask :-)

Comment: According to this topic, onPostExecute runs on UI Thread. But it hasn't solved the updating of first fragment

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348979/call-runonuithread-from-asynchtask

Comment: you should call the runOnUiThread wherever you want to update the textview,